# Sass: Correct hue and saturation difference between three HSL colors

Tags: css, colors, sass

I have three colors that I'm trying to desaturate/saturate, adjust lightness and adjust hue because the lighter and darker shade HSL is different from the base color.

So I can, in the end, add another color as the primary and have a new color scheme based on this one. Hope this makes sense.

How can I do this with HSL colors? Here are my colors in HSL:

```
$primary: hsl(204, 64%, 44%);
$primary-dark: hsl(203, 64%, 23%);
$primary-light: hsl(204, 51%, 55%);
```

And here they are in hex:

```
$primary: #2980B9;
$primary-dark: #154360;
$primary-light: #5499C7;
```

And this is what I've tried so far, but none of it is working - it's not giving me the correct color codes. It's always off by a few numbers. For example, in the example one $primary-light ends up being #5298c7, when I want it to be #5499C7.

[Example one](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXQGRG),
[example two](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRVxWa).

**EDIT:** I've realized that in Example two, adjust-hue function where I subtracted 1deg, is not doing anything at all. Which means I'll need to change the format of how I'm applying these color functions, right? Is there a way I can include them all in one function/mixin? Sorry if this ended up sounding confusing, just trying to figure it out.

Comment: This is over my head/expertise. But is there anything in the W3C docs that can help you out perhaps? https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/

Answer (score 2):

You can use build in [color functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#hsl_functions) to extract color components.
For example:

```
// Your base color
$primary: hsl(204, 64%, 44%); 

// Get all color components and store them to variables
$hue:        hue($primary);
$saturation: saturation($primary);
$lightness:  lightness($primary);

// New color hue
$new-hue: 200;

// Create new color from existing color components
// using hsl() constructor
$color: hsl(
  $new-hue, 
  $saturation, 
  $lightness
);

a {
  // Use new color
  color: $color;
}
```

You can extract hue (for example) component from color that is set as RGB: `$hue: hue(#f00);`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, but how would this work if I had to add another color as primary? So it changes the color scheme?

Comment: For example, I tried this so I'd be able to make this reusable and working with other color schemes, but it's not working, not giving me the correct color codes: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXQGRG  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Or something like this, though the color code is still off from the original primary-dark: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRVxWa